# how to covert dates with just year-month into year-month-date in R?

Tags: r

I have a list of program dates as character strings in the following format

```
program.date.have <-c('Sep-14','Aug-14','Sep-16')
```

I am assuming that all these programs started on the first day of each month, and I want the program.date to end up like

`program.date.want<-c('2014-09-01', '2014-08-01, '2016-09-01')` or in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

To start somewhere I have decided to covert the character strings into the date format in the following way

```
program.date.have<-c('Sep-14','Aug-14','Sep-16')
betterDates <- as.Date(program.date,
                       format = "%m-%y")
```

But even that does not seem to work. how do I use values in `program.date` variable to be converted into format I want in `program.date.want`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `as.yearmon` from `zoo`, specify the `format`, and wrap with `as.Date` which automatically generates the 'day' as the first of the month.

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(program.date.have, "%b-%y"))
#[1] "2014-09-01" "2014-08-01" "2016-09-01"
```

---

Or a `base R` option is to `paste` the '01' at the start or end and then specify the appropriate `format` in `as.Date`

```
as.Date(paste0(program.date.have, "-01"), "%b-%y-%d")
#[1] "2014-09-01" "2014-08-01" "2016-09-01"
```